# How can I set an address like- 'sub-domain.elasticbeanstalk.com' in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ebs, awsdeploy

I have deployed my django project into AWS ELASTIC BEANSTALK (AWS EB). The default public address of the project is in this form: `env-name.region-name.elasticbeanstalk.com`.

After some searching I've found out I can modify the `env-name` portion using modifying the CNAME and I have applied it. It worked!

But, when I tried to set up a direct sub-domain like `subdomain-name.elasticbeanstalk.com` I couldn't do this. I have searched for a while by different search term, but I couldn't find out a way to do that.

**So, my questions are**-

Is it even possible to create this form of address: `subdomain-name.elasticbeanstalk.com`?

If it's possible, then how can I do that?

[OPTIONAL] If it's not possible, then can anyone will be able to give me an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1;

This is not possible, all environments have the region in the url, this is because the dns is routed to this specific region.

Question 3;

I would suggest using your own custom domain and setup an alias/cname record to point to your beanstalk environments, [explained in this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable confirmation.